# jQuery: do some checks without .each()

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to check if any submenu is visible for a menu. Basically I need to know if any submenu of the root menu items is visible.

The problem is that I always get it to work for the first `<li>`, does not take the others into account.

```js
var subm = $('#nav > li').children('.dropdown-menu');
if ( $(subm).css('display') !== 'none' || $(subm).css('opacity') === 1 ) {
  //do this
  console.log('one of more submenus are visible');
} else {
  //do that
  console.log('no submenus visible');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>Menu 1
    <ul class="drodown-menu">some items</ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 2
    <ul class="drodown-menu">some items</ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 3
    <ul class="drodown-menu">some items</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any reply :)

Comment: `$('ul.drodown-menu:visible').length > 0`

Comment: @Phylogenesis, not sure if this also applies to opacity:0 submenus, and I need to make sure of that as well in my case.

Comment: No, `:visible` selector doesn't care about element's opacity.

Comment: How exactly do you make them visible/invisible ? You could append a class when it becomes visible, say: `im_visible_ul` and then use: `if( $('ul.im_visible_ul').length ){ ... }`

Comment: You could use a for instead of an each to loop over the selected dropdown-menus. Or is the idea not to loop over them?

Comment: @phillip100 there are two cases: 1. visible/hidden via class toggle for opacity on desktops and 2. visible/hidden via slideToggle on mobiles. That is why I need it just like that I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('ul.drodown-menu:visible').length > 0)
{
   console.log('one of more submenus are visible');
}
else
{
   console.log('no submenus visible');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the OP comment on the question:

> there are two cases: 1. visible/hidden via class toggle for opacity on desktops and 2. visible/hidden via slideToggle on mobiles. That is why I need it just like that I wrote in the question.

I'd suggest this:

Add this for mobile part:

```
$(your_selector).slideToggle(200, function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('im_invisible');
});
```

Then check whether any `ul` element `:not(ul.im_invisible)` exists:

```
if( $('ul.drodown-menu:not(ul.im_invisible)').length ){
    //do this
    console.log('one of more submenus are visible');
}else{
    //do taht
    console.log('no submenus visible');
}
```

Do the same (toggle `im_invisible`) when toggling `hide` class on desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

The <li> items get the `open` class on hover, so the code that solves for me goes like this.

```js
if ( $('#nav > li > .dropdown:visible').length !== 0 || $('#nav > li.open').length !== 0 ) {
  //do this
  console.log('one of more submenus are visible');
} else {
  //do that
  console.log('no submenus visible');
}
```